# Widget accessibility in all applications

Tags: aviarc

How do I copy a widget to a place where it will be available for all projects in an installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a widget namespace available to all applications by copying it to `<aviarc-data>/widgets`, and then restarting Aviarc. (This is also the folder where the default widget namespaces `com.aviarc.toronto.widget.core*` are located.)

If your widget isn't namespaced, copy it to something like `<aviarc-data>/widgets/awesome-widget-namespace/1.0.0/widgets/<your-widget>`.